# Monitor incoming traffic on ports 80 & 443, vanilla VPS, recycled IP address

Tags: http, https, vps

On a newly-created Debian (or derivative) server operating system, how can I a) check for the existence of, b) roughly quantify, and c) see the origin of any junk/DoS traffic on ports 80 and 443, prior to securing the operating system and before a web server is installed?

**Background**
I use cloud VPS providers for my servers (e.g. DigitalOcean etc). I create a new/vanilla server environment from the host-provided image, typically Debian or Ubuntu, and check its IP addresses on various blocklists to ensure I'm not wasting my time on a 'bad' server. Assuming the server is not listed, I start building it. I secure it, add various system libraries, a mail server, a web server, and only then can I see what level of junk traffic (if any) is being sent to that IP address.

After some years of doing this without issue, I built a web server last week where the assigned IPv4 address was receiving ~100Mbps of junk traffic. I didn't know this was the case until a few hours into the build process and only *after* I'd installed the web server, web application firewall, and server monitoring tools when the log files were ballooning in size.

My very first task on any new web-viewable server is to install a software firewall with minimal ports open. I'm very interested in some kind of sanity check on ports 80 and 443 at an early stage of the build process, before or after the firewall is set up. Without wishing to sound entitled, if the IP addresses are under attack (perhaps weasel wording here), then I'll start over on another assigned address.

Answer (score 1):

After some further research, I found `conntrack` achieves what I need -- specifically `conntrack -E` provides a list of active incoming connections.

Comment: Nice! I wonder if you have to start a firewall first before you can expect this command to work.  I think maybe the answer is that in a VPS, you can't load kernel modules, therefore the conntrack kernel module will have to have been loaded already.  So in a VPS, I guess this command will work even if you have not started a firewall yet.  (Equally, if the conntrack kernel module has not been loaded, then you will *never* be able to use conntrack inside the VPS, so it doesn't matter which you try to do first :-).

Comment: @sourcejedi - yes, it appears so - but my testing has been limited. A vanilla DigitalOcean VPS with no firewall installed returned nothing after a minute or so of `conntrack -E`. Install the firewall, spin it up again, lots of to-and-fro.